# Gradle commands fail on API 23 Google API emulator image (armeabi-v7a)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-gradle-plugin

I can't seem to get Gradle commands from the command line to work with the API 23 Google API emulator image (`Google APIs ARM (armeabi-v7a)`) - I always get a `com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException`.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an AVD with API 23 `Google APIs ARM (armeabi-v7a)`
2. Clone https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils (or use your own project)
3. Run `gradlew installDebug` from the command line

You'll see:

> :demo:assembleDebug
>   :demo:installDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':demo:installDebug'.
>   com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException

If you run `gradlew connectedCheck` you'll see a similar error:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':library:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
>     com.android.builder.testing.api.TestException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException

I **can** install/run the project and tests from Android Studio (1.4) without any problems.

Gradle commands seem to run fine on the **API 21** Google API emulator image from the command line.

Here is an example failure on Travis for API 23 Google API emulator image:

https://travis-ci.org/barbeau/android-maps-utils/builds/83233500

...and an example successful build when using the API 21 Google API emulator image:

https://travis-ci.org/barbeau/android-maps-utils/builds/83234555

The only difference between the two builds is the Google API emulator API level of 23 vs. 21:

https://github.com/barbeau/android-maps-utils/commit/a5eecd7e7a4fc899ecd5eaeae6826414fefeae70

**EDIT**

I've opened an AOSP issue here on this problem:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190200

Comment: I have the same problem. Quite frustrating.

Comment: @BrianCunnie agreed -  I plan to open an AOSP issue about this, just havne't found the time.  Also, FYI - apparently the API Level 22 emulator is messed up too - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176348&thanks=176348&ts=1433887196.

Comment: Ok, just opened an AOSP issue here - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190200.

Comment: Did you reproduce it locally? I followed your steps now and it works on my machine. Probably will be solved on Travis-ci after they update their VM, normally newest emulator not preinstalled fails before that https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/blob/master/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/attributes/default.rb

Comment: Yes, I reproduced it locally at the time.  I'll try again now and see if it works.

Comment: Just followed steps again (using `Google APIs ARM EAMI v7a System Image` version `Rev. 7` in SDK Manager) and I can still reproduce this locally on a Windows 7 Enterprise machine.  `gradlew installDebug` fails from command line with `com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException`.  Interestingly, trying to install from Android Studio resulted in the emulator "power-cycling" - haven't seen that before.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I reproduced it yesterday locally, I'm going to try to solve it now if possible.

Comment: Another hardcoded and restrictive timeout like this one we talked about months ago lol https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69735

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**

Android Gradle Plugin had a hardcoded timeout value that was too low.

Google fixed it in [version 2.0.0-beta3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189764):

> Will be in 2.0.0-beta3.
>
> So what do we put in build.gradle to set this timeout value?
>
> Currently it's all attached to android.adbOptions.timeOutInMs.

Sample: Google project [Increasing ADB timeout](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/commit/da8b766ef770544f79120a2aba60f70dabd47b18) and [adding Travis-ci support](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/commit/807f515f535a4cea06ed8b4299548ed74350a126). It [works](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/android-maps-utils/builds/115625139)!.

---

**Previous response**

It's the [same issue that has been reported here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189764&q=label%3APriority-Medium&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Read the [workaround from the unity3 developer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/testing/ConnectedDevice.java#256) about the hardcoded and low timeout here

and **star** [the issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189764&q=label%3APriority-Medium&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

You are right. It's not a Travis-ci issue, to reproduce it, you only need to create an armeabi-v7a emulator and try to install any app locally from gradle command.

Further information [here, the update3 of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33571279/1009132)

**Update:**

You can avoid the `installVariant` tasks and this issue using adb:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleDebug
./gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest
adb install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
adb install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
adb shell am instrument -w com.google.samples.apps.topeka.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

It works:

```
...
:app:assembleDebugAndroidTest

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 19.787 secs
2413 KB/s (4204090 bytes in 1.701s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Success
1984 KB/s (1058902 bytes in 0.521s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
Success

com.google.samples.apps.topeka.activity.SignInActivityTest:.
com.google.samples.apps.topeka.activity.quiz.EntertainmentQuizTest:.
com.google.samples.apps.topeka.activity.quiz.GeneralKnowledgeQuizTest:..
```

Comment: Thank you for the links to the maps teams repo @ardock