# travis-ci build keeps failing with ShellCommandUnresponsiveException

Tags: android, travis-ci

I'm trying to get travis-ci to work with my android application. If I only execute assembleDebug it works fine. But I want to run tests too and generate code coverage. This is the config I have right now:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    # Uncomment the lines below if you want to
    # use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools

    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-23.0.1

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-23

    # Additional components
    # - extra-google-google_play_services
    # - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    # - addon-google_apis-google-19

    # Specify at least one system image,
    # if you need to run emulator(s) during your tests
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23

env:
  global:
    # install timeout in minutes (2 minutes by default)
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=8

before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew
 - pip install --user codecov

# Emulator Management: Create, Start and Wait
before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force --name test --target android-23 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -no-boot-anim &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script:
  - ./gradlew build connectedCheck --stacktrace
  #  - ./gradlew assembleDebug

after_success:
  - codecov
```

The build keeps failing with `ShellCommandUnresponsiveException`, even though I have set the `ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT` global variable to 8 ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949722/android-tests-fail-on-travis-with-shellcommandunresponsiveexception)). The build itself doesn't even run for 8 minutes, so it's weird why it fails.

I tried deleting all the asset files to make the app as small as possible. But that didn't help.

The failed builds can be found here: https://travis-ci.org/Longi94/bptf/branches under the `travis` branch where I was trying to get it work. There was one successful build. I have no idea how it passed.

Here's a part of a failed build log:

```
[0K$ echo no | android create avd --force --name test --target android-23 --abi armeabi-v7a
Android 6.0 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]Created AVD 'test' based on Android 6.0, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
with the following hardware config:
hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.ramSize=512
vm.heapSize=48
travis_time:end:1030008c:start=1446127538783461373,finish=1446127542625988764,duration=3842527391
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_script.1
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_script.2
[0Ktravis_time:start:16b2cef4
[0K$ emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -no-boot-anim &
travis_time:end:16b2cef4:start=1446127542630405331,finish=1446127542635242867,duration=4837536
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_script.2
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_script.3
[0Ktravis_time:start:00e87790
[0K$ android-wait-for-emulator
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
Waiting for emulator to start
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 576716800
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7040
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 2200
    Label: 
    Blocks: 140800
    Block groups: 5
    Reserved block group size: 39
Created filesystem with 11/35200 inodes and 4536/140800 blocks
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 140800 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: UpdateCheck: current version '24.4.1', last version '24.4.1'
Waiting for emulator to start
... (pruned due to character limit)
Waiting for emulator to start
Emulator is ready
travis_time:end:00e87790:start=1446127542639319959,finish=1446127617455640922,duration=74816320963
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_script.3
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_script.4
[0Ktravis_time:start:0b2fd946
[0K$ adb shell input keyevent 82 &
travis_time:end:0b2fd946:start=1446127617473299362,finish=1446127617478276750,duration=4977388
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_script.4
[0Ktravis_time:start:248749b0
[0K$ ./gradlew build connectedCheck --stacktrace
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
................................................................................
Unzipping /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/6dibv5rcnnqlfbq9klf8imrndn/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip to /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/6dibv5rcnnqlfbq9klf8imrndn
Set executable permissions for: /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/6dibv5rcnnqlfbq9klf8imrndn/gradle-2.2.1/bin/gradle
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3.0/gradle-1.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/1.3.0/gradle-core-1.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/1.3.0/builder-1.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/24.3.0/lint-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/5.2.1/proguard-gradle-5.2.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-parent/5.2.1/proguard-parent-5.2.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/1.3.0/builder-model-1.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/1.3.0/builder-test-api-1.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdklib/24.3.0/sdklib-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/24.3.0/sdk-common-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/24.3.0/common-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/24.3.0/manifest-merger-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/24.3.0/ddmlib-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/5.0.3/asm-parent-5.0.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/ow2/1.3/ow2-1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.3/asm-tree-5.0.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jack/jack-api/0.9.0/jack-api-0.9.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jill/jill-api/0.9.0/jill-api-0.9.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/24.3.0/lint-checks-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj-4.4.2.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/5.2.1/proguard-base-5.2.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/annotations/24.3.0/annotations-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/24.3.0/layoutlib-api-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/24.3.0/dvlib-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/33/commons-parent-33.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1/httpclient-4.1.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1.1/httpcomponents-client-4.1.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/4.1.1/project-4.1.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/httpmime-4.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1/httpcomponents-client-4.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava-parent/17.0/guava-parent-17.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/24.3.0/lint-api-24.3.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.3/asm-analysis-5.0.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/intellij/annotations/12.0/annotations-12.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/httpcore-4.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-core/4.1/httpcomponents-core-4.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/11/commons-parent-11.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.3/lombok-ast-0.2.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3.0/gradle-1.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/1.3.0/gradle-core-1.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/1.3.0/builder-1.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/24.3.0/lint-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/5.2.1/proguard-gradle-5.2.1.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/1.3.0/builder-model-1.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/1.3.0/builder-test-api-1.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdklib/24.3.0/sdklib-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/24.3.0/sdk-common-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/24.3.0/common-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/24.3.0/manifest-merger-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/24.3.0/ddmlib-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.3/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jack/jack-api/0.9.0/jack-api-0.9.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jill/jill-api/0.9.0/jill-api-0.9.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/24.3.0/lint-checks-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj-4.4.2.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/5.2.1/proguard-base-5.2.1.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/annotations/24.3.0/annotations-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/24.3.0/layoutlib-api-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/24.3.0/dvlib-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1/httpclient-4.1.1.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/httpmime-4.1.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/24.3.0/lint-api-24.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.3/asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/intellij/annotations/12.0/annotations-12.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/httpcore-4.1.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.3/lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.4.201502262128.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.build/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.build-0.7.4.201502262128.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.4.201502262128.jar
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72310Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavacNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:unzipJacocoAgent
:app:instrumentDebug
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.ant/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.ant-0.7.4.201502262128.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.core-0.7.4.201502262128.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.report-0.7.4.201502262128.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.1/asm-debug-all-5.0.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/5.0.1/asm-parent-5.0.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.ant/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.ant-0.7.4.201502262128.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.core-0.7.4.201502262128.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.report-0.7.4.201502262128.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.1/asm-debug-all-5.0.1.jar
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
:app:zipalignDebug
:app:assembleDebug
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavacNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:preDexRelease
:app:dexRelease
:app:packageRelease
:app:assembleRelease
:app:assemble
:app:compileLint
:app:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 102 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 102 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:/home/travis/build/Longi94/bptf/app/build/outputs/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to /home/travis/build/Longi94/bptf/app/build/outputs/lint-results.xml
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:app:assembleDebugUnitTest
:app:testDebugUnitTest
:app:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies
:app:processReleaseUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleReleaseUnitTest
:app:testReleaseUnitTest
:app:test
:app:check
:app:build
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:preDexDebugAndroidTest
:app:dexDebugAndroidTest
:app:packageDebugAndroidTest
:app:assembleDebugAndroidTest
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.TestException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.builder.testing.api.TestException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.testing.api.TestException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
    at com.android.builder.testing.SimpleTestRunner.runTests(SimpleTestRunner.java:93)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.runTests(DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.java:112)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.getDeviceConfig(ConnectedDevice.java:259)
    at com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceConfigProviderImpl.<init>(DeviceConfigProviderImpl.java:36)
    at com.android.builder.testing.SimpleTestRunner.runTests(SimpleTestRunner.java:91)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:511)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:388)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:577)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.executeShellCommand(ConnectedDevice.java:136)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.getDeviceConfig(ConnectedDevice.java:256)
    ... 58 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3 mins 27.125 secs
travis_time:end:248749b0:start=1446127617481908384,finish=1446127825369726746,duration=207887818362
[0K
[31;1mThe command "./gradlew build connectedCheck --stacktrace" exited with 1.[0m

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT after ProbleSlover's suggestion:**

After removing the `platform-tools` and `tools` lines. It seemed like the build didn't wait long enough for the emulator to start previously. Now there is a lot of waiting and the build timeouts with the following error:

```
Waiting for emulator to start

Timeout (360 seconds) reached; failed to start emulator
The command "android-wait-for-emulator" failed and exited with 1 during .

Your build has been stopped.
```

Comment: Try to Make Changes cording this build
https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although there is progress, there are still problems. Please see the edit in my post.

Comment: Hey. As I can see the build has been successful.
https://travis-ci.org/Longi94/bptf/builds/88235059

Comment: Yes, after a lot of trial and error I now have a config that mostly succeeds but not always. Yesterday another project of mine failed with the same exception and the same config.

Comment: To be honest I didn't work with travis for a while. I can help you by just sending helpful links xD So checkout the second one
https://github.com/pockethub/PocketHub/blob/master/.travis.yml
If it doesn't work for you. check your application tests..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**

Android Gradle Plugin had a hardcoded timeout value that was too low.

Google fixed it in [version 2.0.0-beta3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189764):

> Will be in 2.0.0-beta3.
>
> So what do we put in build.gradle to set this timeout value?
>
> Currently it's all attached to android.adbOptions.timeOutInMs.

Sample: Google project [Increasing ADB timeout](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/commit/da8b766ef770544f79120a2aba60f70dabd47b18) and [adding Travis-ci support](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/commit/807f515f535a4cea06ed8b4299548ed74350a126). It [works](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/android-maps-utils/builds/115625139)!

---

**Previous response**

You are disabling the boot anim and the `android-wait-for-emulator` script depends on it, so the default script exits from the loop before the emulator is ready. Read [this great explanation](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/).

I wrote about it when the script was bugged [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084948/com-android-builder-testing-connecteddevice-hasteststestavd-5-0-failed/27085247#27085247)

Now the script works and you only need to delete `-no-boot-anim` here:

```
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
```

Alternatively, you can disable the boot animation that speeds up it, but you need to modify the script adding the time you know is enough for your emulator to be ready.

Sometimes I do it, like [here](https://github.com/ardock/android-testing/blob/develop4/scripts/acib#L22)

```
# Wait for device ready
function wait-for-device-ready {
    local bootanim=""
    local failcounter=0
    until [[ "$bootanim" =~ "stopped" ]]; do
       bootanim=`adb hell getprop init.svc.bootanim 2>&1`
       echo "$bootanim"
       if [[ "$bootanim" =~ "not found" ]]; then
          let "failcounter += 1"
          if [[ ${failcounter} -gt 30 ]]; then
            echo "Failed to start emulator"
            exit 1
          fi
       fi
       sleep 1
    done
    sleep 30
    adb shell input keyevent 82 &
    sleep 150
    echo "Done"
}
```

**Update**: Now that I remember, my response is correct in general but other causes produce this issue, especially on android-23, and it is possible that you still see the same error after using my suggestion, [see](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/android-testing/builds/87142295).

I'm not sure about the other issue regarding the android-23 case, I need to investigate it, but I'm not currently using Travis-ci, only a phew tests. I think android-23 is not preinstalled and you need update tools and platform-tools, sometimes I see some apps crash when my emulator api 23 starts at home, etc. It's hard to know the reason without seeing it, but you can add logs to try to see what is happening, inspect [my script](https://github.com/ardock/android-testing/blob/develop4/.travis.yml#L21) for that.

**Update2**:

Open [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952413/gradle-commands-fail-on-api-23-google-api-emulator-image-armeabi-v7a) and [android issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190200) about this error on android-23.

**Update3**:

[Cause: Hardcoded and too low timeout=5, line 256](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/testing/ConnectedDevice.java#256)

```
try {
    executeShellCommand("am get-config", receiver, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return DeviceConfig.Builder.parse(output);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new DeviceException(e);
}
```

Error is reproducible locally:

```
08:22:53.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
08:22:53.795 " Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
08:22:53.795 "        at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:511)
08:22:53.795 "        at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:388)
08:22:53.795 "        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:577)
08:22:53.796 "        at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.executeShellCommand(ConnectedDevice.java:136)
08:22:53.796 "        at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.getDeviceConfig(ConnectedDevice.java:256) <--------
08:22:53.796 "        ... 78 more
```

[Please star this issue, and read the unity3d workaround](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189764&q=label%3APriority-Medium&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

**Update4:**

You can use adb as a work around, I tested it works on [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/android-topeka/builds/94113265):

```
#!/bin/bash

############  ###########  ##########  #########  ########  #######  ######  #####  ####  ###  ##  #
##
##  ACIB SCRIPT
##
############  ###########  ##########  #########  ########  #######  ######  #####  ####  ###  ##  #

# Run android tests
function android-test {
    adb shell input keyevent 82 &
    ./gradlew assembleDebug -PdisablePreDex
    ./gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex
    adb install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
    adb install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
    adb shell pm grant com.google.samples.apps.topeka android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE
    adb shell am instrument -w  -e numShards 6 -e shardIndex 0 -e package com.google.samples.apps.topeka com.google.samples.apps.topeka.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    adb shell am instrument -w  -e numShards 6 -e shardIndex 1 -e package com.google.samples.apps.topeka com.google.samples.apps.topeka.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    adb shell am instrument -w  -e numShards 6 -e shardIndex 2 -e package com.google.samples.apps.topeka com.google.samples.apps.topeka.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    adb shell am instrument -w  -e numShards 6 -e shardIndex 3 -e package com.google.samples.apps.topeka com.google.samples.apps.topeka.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    adb shell am instrument -w  -e numShards 6 -e shardIndex 4 -e package com.google.samples.apps.topeka com.google.samples.apps.topeka.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    adb shell am instrument -w  -e numShards 6 -e shardIndex 5 -e package com.google.samples.apps.topeka com.google.samples.apps.topeka.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
}
```

I need to fix it, but the installation is successful, no timeouts.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I did solve it some time ago by basicly doing the things you suggested (enabling boot-anim and using a android-22 image for the emulator).

Comment: Nice, thanks for mark it as accepted, anyway, I'll update the response when the real problem will be solved and we can use android-23, It's not a Travis-ci issue as I thought, i reproduced it on my machine yesterday and I'm going to try something :)