# Can't configure travis to work on android project

Tags: android, build, travis-ci

I have found several problems with Travis CI and I have been solving them but the last one I can't.

I'm getting the common error
`com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session`

This is my travis file:

```
language: android

before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew

android:
  components:
    # Uncomment the lines below if you want to
    # use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
    # - platform-tools
    # - tools

    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - tools
    - build-tools-23.0.3

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository

    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-23

    # Specify at least one system image,
    # if you need to run emulator(s) during your tests
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23
    #- sys-img-x86-android-17

env:
  global:
    # install timeout in minutes (2 minutes by default)
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=8

# Emulator Management: Create, Start and Wait
before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force --name test --target android-23 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -gpu off -no-boot-anim &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb devices
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script:
  - echo $ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT
  - android list target
  - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest

after_failure:
  # Customize this line, 'android' is the specific app module name of this project. Shows log.
  - export MY_MOD="SimpleLock"
  - export MY_LOG_DIR="$(pwd)/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/"
  - pwd && cd "${MY_LOG_DIR:-.}" && pwd && ls -al
  - sudo apt-get install -qq lynx && lynx --dump index.html > myIndex.log
  - lynx --dump com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.html > myConnectedDevice.log
  - lynx --dump com.android.builder.testing.html > myTesting.log
  - for file in *.log; do echo "$file"; echo "====================="; cat "$file"; done || true
```

And this is my travis output:
https://travis-ci.org/GarceGon/SimpleLock/builds/139367600

```
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTestUnable to install /home/travis/build/GarceGon/SimpleLock/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session
    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:66)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:901)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:119)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:121)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > runTests[test(AVD) - 6.0] FAILED 
    com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session
        at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:129)
null
com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:129)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:121)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session
    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:66)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:901)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:119)
    ... 8 more
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/travis/build/GarceGon/SimpleLock/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 2 mins 20.531 secs
The command "./gradlew connectedAndroidTest" exited with 1.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

Delete `-no-boot-anim` option to wait for emulator ready and increase timeout to 10 minutes.

---

**First issue:**

Replace

```
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -gpu off -no-boot-anim &
```

By

```
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -gpu off &
```

Deleting -`no-boot-anim` option, `android-wait-for-emulator` script depends on boot animation to detect when the emulator is ready as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948976/1009132).

I forked your project to confirm this on a develop branch and the Travis-CI build [passed](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/SimpleLock/builds) but...

---

**Second issue:**

Later I recreated the change using the master branch and the build [failed](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/SimpleLock/builds)...

```
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
```

You already fixed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28949723/1009132) version of the issue very well explained by Sean Barbeau:

```
# install timeout in minutes (2 minutes by default)
- ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=8
```

and you also fixed another timeout issue explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33571279/1009132) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33580613/1009132) that needs more time, [see](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/commit/72c9a1572eb9707d6986ceb35a390dbca5d9e622):

> Android Gradle Plugin had a hard coded timeout value that was too low.
>
> Google fixed it (version 2.0.0-beta3):
>
> https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189764
>
> So what do we put in build.gradle to set this timeout value?
>
> Currently it's all attached to android.adbOptions.timeOutInMs.
>
> Sample: Google project [Increasing ADB timeout](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/commit/da8b766ef770544f79120a2aba60f70dabd47b18) and [adding Travis-ci support](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/commit/807f515f535a4cea06ed8b4299548ed74350a126). It [works](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/android-maps-utils/builds/115625139)!

```
// This enables long timeouts required on slow environments, e.g. Travis
adbOptions {
    timeOutInMs 10 * 60 * 1000  // Set the timeout to 10 minutes
    installOptions "-d","-t"
}
```

I increased the timeout from 1 to 10 minutes like Mark McDonald did, and the build [passed](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/SimpleLock/builds):

[image]

Comment: Still not working for me :(
https://travis-ci.org/GuilhE/SharedPrefsUtils/builds/449764851 using Gradle Plugin 3.2.1

Answer (score 2):

Try few things

- Make sure that Emulator is launched / Device is connected
- Restart adb with `$ adb kill-server`
- Check that emulator setting "Use Host GPU" is enabled