# Gradle task createDebugCoverageReport on TeamCity fails with exception ShellCommandUnresponsiveException

Tags: android, gradle, teamcity

I'm running Jacoco's `createDebugCoverageReport` task for an Android project within Docker on TeamCity for continuous integration. Even before `createDebugCoverageReport` is executed, the build fails at task `connectedDebugAndroidTest` with exception of `com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException`

log:

```
[21:17:31][Step 3/4] :app:validateDebugSigning
[21:17:31][Step 3/4] :app:packageDebugAndroidTest
[21:17:31][Step 3/4] :app:assembleDebugAndroidTest
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] 
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] 
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] * What went wrong:
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] > com.android.builder.testing.api.TestException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] 
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] * Try:
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] 
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] BUILD FAILED
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] 
[21:17:41][Step 3/4] Total time: 1 mins 7.214 secs
```

I found a [workaround on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949722/android-tests-fail-on-travis-with-shellcommandunresponsiveexception) for similar problem on Travis but solution is not applicable to TeamCity.